# WPF TreeView construction - does using view / view model for each item is good?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Let's say I have some hierarchical data that I want to display in a `TreeView`.

```
interface IName
{
    string Name
    {
        get;
    }
}

interface IUniversity:IName
{
    IDepartment[] Departments
    {
        get;
    }
}

interface IDepartment:IName
{
    IStudents[] Students
    {
        get;
    }
}

interface IStudent:IName
{

}
```

Now I am getting a collection of `IUniversity` from some `DataService` and I want to display it in `TreeView`.

First approach is to use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` which is the known and commonly used, therefore I will not talk about it. The other approach that I find lately is using `caliburn.micro.View.Model`:

```
<ContentControl cm:View.Model={Binding Universities} />
```

and for each type, I define a relation ship in a Generic View model:

```
class ParentChildenViewModel<TP,TC>
{
    ObservableCollection<TC> Childrens
    {
        get;
    }

    Action<TC> ChildFactory;
}
```

Now each type has correspondet `ViewModel` and a view `IDepartment`:

```
class DepartmentViewModel: ParentChildenViewModel<IDepartment,IStudent>
{
    Action<IStudent> ChildFactory;

    ObservableCollection<IStudent> Childrens
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

So when constructing the DepartmentViewModel, I pass in its constructor:

```
(student => new StudentViewModel(student,...)
```

This will be applied when a new item is added to the collection of children

And I have correspondent View DepartmentView:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

Also for Student I have StudentView:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

and finally at the parent view that shows the Universities:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TVItem" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Childrens}"> 
       <ContentControl cm:View.Model="{Binding}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

So to put things short:
The second solution map each item to a view-viewmodel of its own rather than using template for the a collection view model(first approach)

I am not convinced which approach is better (Finally this is a question):
First approach has much less code, and better performance.
Second is more clear? I think
Especially important is performance, does the second approach necessarily more expensive?

Comment: Option 2 seems to be creating more objects so one would think that it is a bit slower, but if you really care about performance then you should use some performance tests with a huge data set using both techniques and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I would always favor cleanliness and readability over premature optimization. As Sniffer points out, the only way to optimize properly is to run tests using large data sets over both and see which one wins out. I generally find though that computers run much faster than I tend to give the credit for.